# Accessing applications on another VPS

Tags: iptables, linode, redis

I'm doing something that (to me) seems very simple, but perhaps I'm looking at the problem wrong.

I've deployed a Redis box to Linode. I have a number of web servers that also sit on Linode (in the same data center). I'd like the web servers to access the Redis installations.

Through some research on the Google, I'm led to believe that I just need to do some tweaking of `iptables`. Do you concur? How can I say, "Hey, PHP! Connect to the redis on that other server!"

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you would have 2 options.

1) Have php connect to it using the ip address of the other VPS just like it was 2 physical servers in different locations.

2) Ask Linode if you can have/use internal ip addresses like you would use at home and tell php to connect to the internal ip of that other vps.

could be other methods but those are the 2 easiest that come to mind.

using VPS's is no different then using real physical boxes really.

Comment: I was just wondering how to configure the Redis box so that I *could* connect to it from the webserver. Is it possible to only allow connections from a particular IP?